# JSONDecodeErrror while trying to decide JSON from file

Tags: python, json, blockchain

I am trying to create a very simple blockchain with Python.

```
import json
import os
import hashlib


blockchain_dir = os.curdir + "/blockchain/"
```

The code can save blocks, but if want to use the `check_integrity` function I get an `JSONDecodeError`:

```
def get_hash(filename):
    
    file = open(blockchain_dir + filename, "rb").read()     
    return hashlib.md5(file).hexdigest()


def get_files():

    files = os.listdir(blockchain_dir)                                 
    return sorted([int(i) for i in files])                             
    


def check_integrity():                                             

    files = get_files()

    results = []

    for file in files[:1]:                                          
        f = open(blockchain_dir + str(file))
        h = json.load(f)['hash']                                   
        prev_file = str(file - 1)                                   
        actual_hash = get_hash(prev_file)                           
        if h == actual_hash:
            res = 'OK'
        else:
            res = 'Corrupted'
        
        results.append({'block': prev_file, 'result': res})

    return results


def write_block(name, amount, to_whom, prev_hash=''):                      
    
    files = get_files()

    prev_file = files[-1]
    file_name = str(prev_file + 1)

    prev_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file))        
    
    data = {"name": name,
            "amount": amount,
            "to_whom": to_whom,
            "hash": prev_hash}
    
    with open(blockchain_dir + file_name, "w") as file:                              
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)     


def main():
    write_block("Friend", 120, "Me")
    print(check_integrity())

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Python/blockchain/block.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Python/blockchain/block.py", line 64, in main
    print(check_integrity())
  File "/Python/blockchain/block.py", line 31, in check_integrity
    h = json.load(f)['hash']                                   # method load - take object and return json object, hash - it is key in the block file, we get hash from the block file and compare it with hash that we get after function get_hash
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: looks like your json file is invalid. can you pass it through a json validator?

Comment: Looks like your json is *empty*.

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: print the name of the file you are trying to open. In some devices like a Mac, there are some system files that are generated. Maybe you are opening one of them. Just print the result of os.listdir and see what the output is.

Comment: yes, answer was 'None', thank you, will try to solve why

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the json file you're trying to parse is empty.I'm not familiar with any method to automatically check if a json file is empty, apart from checking for such an occurrence manually. You can manually check and confirm whether a json file is empty by adding a try-except statement in your check integrity function i.e:

```
try:
   h = json.load(f)['hash']
except KeyError:
   ...
```

The keyerror catches a scenario where the "hash" key is empty therefore suggesting the data your trying to access doesn't exist.